# Pickerview in Actionsheet displaying in iPhone but not in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

Firstly, this is the pictures in iPhone and iPad

iPhone : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/563577Capturedcran20140610125811.png
iPad : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/315654Capturedcran20140610125901.png

This is how I am doing :

```
_questionnairePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,44.0, 320.0, 250.0)];
_questionnaireActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Questionnaire"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];


_questionnaireActionSheet.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_dateActionSheet.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.selectedIndexQuestionnaire = 0;
self.questionnairePicker.delegate = self;
[self.questionnaireActionSheet addSubview:[self getToolBarActionSheet:self.questionnairePicker]];
[self.questionnaireActionSheet addSubview:self.questionnairePicker];
```

and

```
 -(UIToolbar *)getToolBarActionSheet:(UIView *)aPicker
    {

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClick:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                  target:self action:@selector(pickerCancelClick:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                             target:self action:nil];


    if(aPicker.tag == 2) doneBtn.tag = cancelBtn.tag = 2;


    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
    [barItems addObject:flex];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    return pickerToolbar;
}
```

So, someone know a good way to resolve it ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerViews on the ipad don't have a default size (ie width).

change

```
_questionnairePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,44.0, 320.0, 250.0)];
```

to

```
_questionnairePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 400, 216)];
```

Comment: Same problem .. The problem is not the width but the height

Comment: _questionnairePicker.deleget=self;